# cant' create custom BSgenome (BSgenomeForge)

Tags: r

I've been trying to build a custom bovine `BSgenome` using [NCBI UMD3.1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/GCF_000003055.6) assembly.

I followed the manual in the [BSgenomeForge](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/BSgenome/inst/doc/BSgenomeForge.pdf) page but kept getting an error.

```
library(BSgenome)
forgeBSgenomeDataPkg("/PATH/TO/genome.fa")
Error: Line starting '>10 ...' is malformed!
```

Should the file have a certain form to work?

Can somebody tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you make your question reproducible? At the very least, provide us with enough information about the error message and your data so that we can at least make an educated guess of what's going wrong. Have you tried running any examples to see if your toolchain works fine and dandy?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but the code above is all I got. FYI, my system is Ubuntu14.04, R-3.1.3. Genome sequence was downloaded from iGenomes NCBI UMD3.1. That's all I can think of now.